# Is a variable stored in Session deserialized once or multiple times throughout a page lifecycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I would like to wrap Session variables in a manner similar to that [discussed on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wrapthosesessionvariables.aspx?msg=2315287).

```
public static class WebSession
{
  private const string CurrentUserKey = "CurrentUser";

  private static HttpSessionState Session
  {
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
  }

  public static bool Exists
  {
    get { return Session != null; }
  }

  public static User CurrentUser
  {
    get { return Session[CurrentUserKey] as User; }
    set { Session[CurrentUserKey] = value; }
  }
}
```

Here is my question: if I have to access `CurrentUser` multiple times in the same page, would I get a performance improvement by assigning it to a local variable instead of accessing the wrapping property?  Or does the `HttpSessionState` make sure the object is only deserialized once per request, so that subsequent calls in the same http request don't cost any more?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Not an answer to your question but, using a local variable is faster then getting your variable from a collection.

Comment: If I were to add some more relevance to your question,  "When does session serialization and deserialization take place and when it takes place,are all objects serialized/deserialized  and if I were to call the same (serialized) session object multiple times, is it fetched/deserialized once or multiple times ?

Comment: FYI, your class for dealing with Session is nice. If you want to take it up a notch, check out this link: http://blog.theobjectguy.com/2009/12/session-with-style.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an in-memory copy of your Session state on each request. Therefore the only cost that you would be saving by locally copying a session variable is that of the cast from Object to your type. The in-memory copy is then added to Session at the end of the request.

Whether or not Session is serialized and deserialized on a page depends on what Session Provider you choose. For In-proc Session State, no serialization occurs. For Session Servers the object must be serialized first.

Comment: Serialization is StateServer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is an in-memory copy. You get negligible performance improvement from caching the value; it would save only a Dictionary lookup, which will be too fast to notice unless you're doing it a zillion times per page load.

Also important to note is that for a given key, each retrieval returns a reference to the same instance, and Session keeps a reference too. That means, if you retrieve an object from Session and modify it, you need not call the setter again to re-serialize it.

I just asked a question about this same thing:
[Are .Net property setters ever called implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141060)

Comment: Thanks.  I searched before I asked, I promise!

Comment: Yeah, my question came at this from a different direction. I just mentioned it because I wouldn't expect you to have come across it.

Answer (score 3):

I did some work pulling apart session [recently](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/state-assassins-with-experience-of.html), and from what I could see, the entire state object is deserialized once and once only per request. Of course, it is easy enough to check - just fetch it out twice and check `ReferenceEquals`.

Of course, placing the value in a field between uses would save some "lookup" time, but you should only pay the deserialization cost once.

If you *really* wanted to be sure, you could also double-check this by implementing `ISerializable` and logging serialize / deserialize calls.

Answer (score 0):

some good articles to read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx#S5