# Cost of accessing session value

Tags: asp.net, .net

Is there a cost to accessing a session value? Apart from the cost of accessing a (I presume) dictionary. Maybe a session deserialize every time it's being accessed.

For example, I've seen some people put the session value in a variable.

```
_sessionValue = CType(Session(SESSION_NAME), SomeClass)

_sessionValue.SomeFunction1()
_sessionValue.SomeFunction2()
```

And others create a property

```
Public ReadOnly Property SessionValue As SomeClass
    Get
        Return CType(Session(SESSION_NAME), SomeClass)
    End Get
End Property

SessionValue.SomeFunction1()
SessionValue.SomeFunction2()
```

I wonder if there is a significant difference in speed between the two or if one is recommended from the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a variable stored in Session deserialized once or multiple times throughout a page lifecycle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150153/is-a-variable-stored-in-session-deserialized-once-or-multiple-times-throughout-a)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here.  First, those code samples are doing nothing more than casting the session object to a type.  This would be done anyway in the code using the object.  The benefit is that there is a page property that you can easily use in any method.  The session object won't be read and cast as the type unless you make a call to the property.

You should decide for yourself if you want to use a private or public member.  There isn't really any difference between the property and the member.

You can read up on making session state fast [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx)

For details on seralizing and deserializng the session objects check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150153/is-a-variable-stored-in-session-deserialized-once-or-multiple-times-throughout-a) older post.